# Get-NetTCPConnection Browser OwningProcess Only Show One PID

Tags: windows, powershell, process, monitoring

When I get the TCP connections in **PowerShell** by using the PS `C:\> Get-NetTCPConnection` Command, the **OwningProcess** column has many different PIDs, but unfortunately it doesn't show all browser opened tab PID's like Chrome, it will show only one main PID, why? and how to fix it?

[image: Get-NetTCPConnection output]

[image: Task manager output]

Comment: Because that's how chrome works - one process manages the connection pool

Comment: Thank you @Mathias R. Jessen, any way to fix it, please?

Comment: Not sure I understand, there's nothing to fix?